# Python If statement using 'and' with 'in'

Tags: python, if-statement

I'm trying to go parse some text and looking for certain patterns.  One pattern I'm looking for is strings that contain both ' AS ' and '.'.

Assuming I have a list of strings, I'm using this to find and append select strings to a new list.

```
list1 = []

for ngram in bigrams:
        if ' AS ' and '.' in ngram:
            list1.append(ngram)
```

This is not working, it appears to be functioning more like:

```
    if ' AS ' or '.' in ngram:
```

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 2):

```
if ' AS ' and '.' in ngram:
```

is parsed as

```
if (' AS ') and ('.' in ngram):
```

that is,

```
if (True) and ('.' in ngram):
```

which is equivalent to just `if '.' in ngram`.

In fact, you cannot use "foo and bar in baz." Try instead:

```
if ' AS ' in ngram and '.' in ngram:
```

Or even better, use that in a list comprehension and change those 5 lines of code into one:

```
list1 = [ngram for ngram in bigrams if ' AS ' in ngram and '.' in ngram]
```